# Getting the max value after being multiplied and added

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me with the codes I'm working with right now.
I just want to show the distinct Max value from the table After being multiplied and added the the 2 columns from 2 different tables.

HERE is my SQL statement for my table:

```
SELECT ol.*
     , SUM((ol.OrderedQuantity)*(SELECT p.ProductStandardPrice FROM product_t p WHERE p.ProductID=ol.ProductID)) AS TotalAmount  
  FROM orderline_t ol 
 GROUP 
    BY ol.OrderID
```

output table shows only the value inside the box using max.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the schema of the tables and give an example of data in them and expected result? Also it would be great that you format the question, so it is easier to read.

Comment: please provide the sample dataset with expected output

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't follow "distinct max value from table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow exactly what you want to do.  However, your query would more colloquially and accurately be written using `JOIN`.  If you want the total *per order* then you don't want all those extraneous columns on the row:

```
SELECT ol.OrderId,
       SUM((ol.OrderedQuantity * p.ProductStandardPrice) AS TotalAmount  
FROM orderline_t ol JOIN
     product_t p 
     ON p.ProductID = ol.ProductID
GROUP BY ol.Order;
```

I suspect that starting with a working query will get you closer to the solution you want.